# Qml font.styleName is not changing on windows

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

I have font(ttf) file , which I load in Qml using FontLoader.
This font is successfully loaded.
But when I use font.styleName. It is not changing font style

```
Text
  {
  text: "Client Name"
  height: 23
  font.pointSize: 20
  font.family: myLoadedFont.name
  font.styleName: "Medium Oblique"
  }
```

On Mac, I am able to use font.styleName, but on windows it is not working.
Is this windows platform specific issue in qt fonts.

Comment: Which Qt Version?

Comment: Qt version 5.9.1

Comment: I wonder if font.styleName works on windows at all. All I know currently is that we are now 3 people seeing this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31305?focusedCommentId=203639&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-203639